# A property of a function which is continuous on a comeager set

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, functions, uniform-continuity

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on a comeager set $A\subseteq X$. Choose $p, q\in A$ with $f(p)\neq f(q)$.

Is it true that there are  open sets $U$ of $p$ and $V$ of $q$ in $X$  such that $f(U)\cap f(V)=\emptyset$?

Note that a set is meager if it is countable union of nowhere dense sets and it  is comeager if it is complement of meager set.

Comment: I think the answer is yes in the stronger assumptio that $f$ be uniformly continuous on $A$.

Comment: @arnett, Thanks. Take $\epsilon< d(f(p), f(q))$. By definition of continuity, there exist open sets $U$ of $p$ and open set $V$ of $q$ with $f(U)\subseteq B(f(p), \epsilon)$ and $f(V)\subseteq B(f(q), \epsilon)$. This implies that $f(U)\cap f(V)=\emptyset$, Is it true?

Comment: No, this does not work for a number of reasons. And I also realized that what I have said is not true. Anyway, I think the result is not true, the following should be a counterexample: take $f:[-1, 1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $x\mapsto 1/(x-1)(x+1)$ if $x \ne \pm 1$ and give distinct, arbitrary values to $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$, like $f(1)=0$ and $f(-1)=1$.

Comment: Even easier, with a function which is uniformly continuous on $A$: take $X=[-1, 1]$ as before and set $f$ to be constant on $A=(-1, 1)$, assign arbitrary distinct values to $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$.